# Is the set $\{\frac{1}{n}$ | $n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ closed in $(0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Is the set $\{\frac{1}{n}$ | $n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ closed in $(0,1]$? I am trying to come up with an example of a set $F$ which is closed and is contained in an open set $U$, but for any $r$, $N_r(F):=\{x\in X$ | $\exists y\in F$ st. $d(x,y)<r\}$ is not contained in $U$. For this example, I take $U=\bigcup\limits_{f\in F} B_{\epsilon_{f}} (f)$ such that each $\epsilon_f$ is chosen so that the only element of $F$ contained in each open ball is $f$ itself.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is the intersection of the closed set $\{0\} \cup \left\{\frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb N\right\}$ with $(0, 1]$.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the set $\{\frac{1}{n}$ | $n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ closed in $(0,1]$?

Yes, it is. Look at $(0,1] \setminus \{ \frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb N^+ \}$. For each $n \in \mathbb N^{+}$ let $U_n = (\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n+1}$). Each $U_n$ is open in $(0,1]$ and
$$
(0,1] \setminus \{ \frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb N^+ \} = \bigcup \{ U_n \mid n \in \mathbb N^+ \}.
$$